# Listen for location and orientation changes

Tags: android, location, orientation, event-listener

I am working on an idea for an android app but it requires me to listen for location changes and orientation changes.

Basically I want to find out if someone is facing towards a certain point, which would require me to find the orientation of the phone. However I also want to keep track of the location changes as I want to know if the user is closer or further away from this point.
I have the location listener sorted so I can look up the location against a number of stored points in my database.

How would I now go about also listening for orientation changes at the same time? Is it possible to implement 2 listeners in the same activity.

By orientation changes I mean changes in the direction the user is facing not phone orientation such as landscape or portrait. So I will be wanting to monitor onSensorChanged and retrieve the azimuth

Answer (score 0):

For listening orientation changes you can use `onConfigurationChanged()`

and add some `configChanges` in your manifest for the `activity`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You requirement separated into 2 parts:

First is the orientation changes, in `AndroidManifest.xml`, register the configuration change of orientation for your `Activity`:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation">
```

In `YourActivity`, override the `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            // Do your stuffs here as LANDSCAPE mode
        }else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //Do your stuffs here as PORTRAIT mode
        }
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Second part, location change, register your `Activity` as the `LocationListener` and implement the `onLocationChanged` method:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // Location changed as loc, do things here
    }
```

And in your `onCreate`:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GPS is enabled");
        GPSListener = new MyLocationListener("GPS");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
                1, this);
    } else {
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NETWORK is enabled");
            NetworkListener = new MyLocationListener("NETWORK");
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited my question slightly, I meant the orientation of the user and not the phones orientation of landscape/portrait. My problem being how would I implement location listener like you described above, as well as sensor listener to get the azimuth.

Comment: Yes, you can implement as many `Listener` as you want in same `Activity`, im not sure about `onSensorChanged` but you could just try yourself, but about the location, as my answer above, you can listen to the location change every second(1000ms) or every meter(1) by changing the variables passed in. Hope this helps.